# Calling StepOut() and EvaluateExpression() in immediate sequence

Tags: lldb

Calling `StepOut()` and then `EvaluateExpression()` in immediate sequence, for example from a script, does not return the expected value.

It does work when manually and separately calling these functions from the console:

```
(lldb) script lldb.thread.StepOut()
(lldb) script print lldb.frame.EvaluateExpression("$rax").description
```

However, it does not work when combining them into one statement:

```
(lldb) script lldb.thread.StepOut(); print lldb.frame.EvaluateExpression("$rax").description
```

This prints `None` to the console.

Checking the process's state shows that there's a difference between the two forms:

```
(lldb) script lldb.thread.StepOut()
(lldb) script print lldb.process.state
```

The state value is `lldb.eStateStopped`.

When running in sequence, the state immediately after `StepOut` is different:

```
(lldb) script lldb.thread.StepOut(); print lldb.process.state
```

Here the state is `lldb.eStateRunning`.

So the questions is:

How should code be written to ensure `StepOut` has fully completed? I'm assuming that requires the state to be back to stopped, and the `frame` to be initialized/setup, before calls to `EvaluateExpression()`?

Answer (score 1):

The lldb SBDebugger can run in either synchronous or asynchronous mode.

In async mode, the commands that cause the debugee to run return as soon as it starts running.  That's useful if you are planning control the whole debug session, handling events yourself, etc.  There's an example of doing that here:

http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/lldb/trunk/examples/python/process_events.py

In synchronous mode, StepOut won't return till the debugee stops again.  That mode is more convenient for one-off commands like the ones you show.

You can set the mode on the debugee using the "SBDebugger.SetAsync" call, passing True for async, and False for sync.

Comment: I should have mentioned async. If I call `SetAsync(False)` before `StepOut()`, then lldb (client) is put into an unusable state. Specifically, the thread does not appear to step-out, it's unclear what happens, Xcode and the console provide no feedback of changes. In addition, after `SetAsync(False)`, the next command run, even just `help`, hangs indefinitely. I thought async property only applied to `Continue()`, so I didn't think it was relevant to `StepOut()`.

Comment: I have a solution that uses a scripted thread plan. However I hit issues there too. I can get the `summary` of the SBValue, but calling `GetObjectDescription()` causes lldb to hang.

Comment: Did you make sure to set it back to true when you were done?  Xcode will not be very happy in Sync mode.  Whenever I do this in python code I always call GetAsync first, set it to false, then set it back to whatever GetAsync returned on the way out.

Comment: Yep, I tried it both ways. You can see Xcode's disjoint debugging behavior by running a one liner `script`. Here's an example https://gist.github.com/kastiglione/ea2a26fbc1470c08e1e64d534f614bd8

Comment: So there is a bug when lldb is embedded in Xcode where if you run a python based command in a breakpoint callback (or stop-hook), Xcode will stall.  If you are using it this way, for now you will have to put the code in a Python breakpoint callback, and add that to the breakpoint.  You can't at present use the Xcode Breakpoint UI features - it doesn't support adding Python callbacks.  So the down-side of this workaround is you will have to make these breakpoints and add the command to them by hand, either in the lldb console or in a command file you source.